# How set ARITHABORT ON at sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I noticed that when I'm executing such code on SQL Server it is executed with `ARITHABORT OFF`. Within my case has a horrible impact on performance (instead of 200ms it can be even 2 minutes).  I don't know how I can enable that option and execute the stored procedure with option `ARITHABORT ON` so in the same way as I'm executing that directly form SQL Server Management Studio.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(self.getSql_conn_url())
query = "exec sp_getVariablesList @City = '{0}', @Station='{1}'".format(City, Station)
self.Variables = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
engine.dispose()
print (self.Variables)
```

Comment: Since your code simply executes a stored procedure, you could set the option in the procedure itself.

Comment: or possibly just prepend the `query` string with `SET ARITHABORT ON;`

Comment: @GordThompson Yeah, sorry to OP, didn't mean to be harsh. It's just that it's a complete XY problem

Comment: `has a horrible impact on performance` that's probably not true. It's probably just a parameter sniffing problem, see [Erland Sommarskog: Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). Please [edit] and add SP code, `CREATE TABLE` definition with indexes, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan Also, you shouldn't prefix stored procedures with `sp_`. And your query is currently open to SQL injection, as you are embedding the parameters as text.

Comment: @Charlieface I was executing that stored procedure with ARITHABORT OFF/ON and that is the main factor of the inefficiency of that query. Also, I compared parameters by checking sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes. When it comes to sp_ you are right that is not the best naming convention still everyone has his habits;). Interesting for me is what you mentioned about SQL injection. Could you advice how should I put parameter for the stored procedure to make that not vulnerable for SQL injection? When it comes to parameters also fully agree but seems that that is not so important for my specific query.

Comment: Not sure as I don't use sqlalchemy, but you should pass through parameters *as parameters* not as text. A quick Google indicates something like `cursor.callproc` but no idea. Again, `ARITHABORT` is not what the difference is, you have two cached plans, one good, one bad, it just so happens that `ARITHABORT ON` is bringing up the good one. You could equally have it the other way round f you cleared the QP cache. Please read that article I linked and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @SM I was not aware that that can be added at the beginning of the stored procedure! but that works. Thank you for your help.