# How correctly execute a MSSQL stored procedure with parameters in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sql-injection

Currently i'm executing stored procedure that way:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(self.getSql_conn_url())
query = "exec sp_getVariablesList @City = '{0}', @Station='{1}'".format(City, Station)
self.Variables = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

but at [How set ARITHABORT ON at sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66679578/how-set-arithabort-on-at-sqlalchemy) was correctly noticed that that make that open to SQL injection. I tried different ways but without success. So how should I pass parameters to the MSSQL stored procedure to eliminate the risk of SQL injection? That can be with sqlalchemy or any other way.

Comment: What code have you tried and why didn't it work for you? (Error messages?) Have you tried reading through the [pandas.read_sqlquery documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) yet? You can pass in parameters via the `params` tuple.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried to do that as is described at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html (Calling Stored Procedures) and received error: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'callproc'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write your SQL command text using the "named" paramstyle, wrap it in a SQLAlchemy `text()` object, and pass the parameter values as a dict:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_uri = "mssql+pyodbc://@mssqlLocal64"
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri)

# SQL command text using "named" paramstyle
sql = """
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
EXEC dbo.breakfast @name = :name_param, @food = :food_param;
"""
# parameter values
param_values = {"name_param": "Gord", "food_param": "bacon"}
# execute query wrapped in SQLAlchemy text() object
df = pd.read_sql_query(sa.text(sql), engine, params=param_values)

print(df)
"""
                           column1
0  Gord likes bacon for breakfast.
"""
```